# Automatic long word breaking in whole document

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

In my document some of long words are not automatically broken at the end of the line. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: could you be more precise as to what exactly the problem looks like? Maybe post a [minimal working example](http://goo.gl/5XLQU) so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: Let me guess: Are some of these very long words hyphenated? TeX won't insert further hyphens into words that are already hyphenated. Please edit your posting to provide some examples of problem words.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have the correct language specified with eg `\usepackage[german]{babel}` then if there are still some words TeX does not know how to hyphenate you can add hyphenation rules in the preamble such as

```
\hyphenation{ve-ry-lon-g-w-ord  ev-en-long-er-com-pound-word-with-no-spaces}
```

and then if either of `verylongword` or `evenlongercompoundwordwithnospaces` appears in the document it may be hyphenated at the indicated places.

Comment: The hyphenation exceptions should be declared after `\begin{document}` or, in the preamble, between `\begin{hyphenrules}{<language>}` and `\end{hyphenrules}`. With `babel` 3.9 there are better facilities.

Comment: Non of the above suggestions worked for me =(

Comment: Ok I discovered that I also have to add `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` after `\begin{document}` and it works. But when using a german vowel like ä or ü in the hyphenation, it doesn't work.

Comment: If German umlauts prevent hyphenation then check and ensure that you use the correct font encoding and optionally also an input encoding that allows you to input German umlauts as a single character. E.g. `\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Without an explicit font encoding the traditional OT1 encoding is used. With this encoding German umlauts are printed as compound characters and those prevent hyphenation.